# Magento Configure Products + Simple Products

Tags: magento, hosting, magento-1.4

**Current Magento setup**:
Configure Products + Simple Products

**Problem**:
Configurable product from 2000 simple products is causing an issue as Magento stops responding if i make configurable products from more than 500 simple products

> Error Message: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2186999 bytes) in /homepages/3/d347795961/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
>
> product name = test
>   Type= configurable
>
> Associated products = 696  simple products
>
> Error Message: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in /homepages/3/d347795961/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/default/flp/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 290
>
> Operating System:  1&1 Dual Core – L Dedicated Server
>   CPU: Opteron1216
>   Clock Rate: 2 x 2.4 GHz
>   Ram: 2GB   (RAID 1 Software)
>   Memory: 40m

**Comments**:
I have been told by my developer that if i obtain a server with 312m memory or more – he recommended a company called www.bluehost.com – this should solve the problem?
I have 3 products with numerous size variants in each – adding up to 2000 possibilities between the 3 different products. I also have 2 more products with approx 1500 size variants or possible combinations, which we have not even attempted to load yet due to the aforementioned.

My developer is now offering “Simple products with custom option” as a solution http://s347795977.websitehome.co.uk/magento/index.php/test-product-4158.html -  this will however doing it this way will apparently not allow me to check stock – which will have direct bearing of trying to integrate Magento into the Sage Accounting package.......I am also not sure of what other problems or restrictions it will raise  i.e  changing pricing easily

**Questions**:
- Is it possible to have numerous variations (size combinations) on a specific  product using Configure Products + Simple Products Setup
- This being the case, if i swop to another server package offering 312m or more – will this solve the problem – and more importantly allow me to lead the additional 1500 products on over and above the 2000 i am currently having a problem with.
Any advice or assistance regarding this matter would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, theoretically it's entirely possible to have large combinations of simple products for a configurable product. In practice, performance problems (such as the one you are experiencing) will limit you.
2. Maybe? Increasing the limit will allow you to bump your PHP memory limit higher (something which you may be able to do even now), but the essential problem of loading that many products is still present.

The first thing to try is to bump PHP's memory limit. 40M is pretty low, and upping it may resolve your problem.

Otherwise, would it be possible to make slightly different permutations for the products? e.g. if the current configurable attributes are foo, bar and baz, make a product for each value of baz to limit the number of configurations?

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

You should raise memory_limit a bit. You can do it in php.ini with vps or dedicated server, also in server allows php.ini custom. Or you can change value in .htaccess

For example:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```